# How to make a pause screen in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a function where when I press <kbd>p</kbd> the game stops and shows "Game Paused".

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding a `is_paused` boolean flag and add `if not is_paused` inside your `update` method to act accordingly (The `update` method is the method that is executed 30 times per second in your game):

Some pseudocode:

```
def update(screen, entities, is_paused):
    if is_paused:
        if is_clicked_button(BUTTON_TO_UNPAUSE):
            is_paused = False
        return
    # Logic on screen, entities and so on...
```